# Pass VM Argument in IntelliJ

Tags: java, virtual-machine

My main() method that creates instances of my Game Class and GUI class (implementing  a board game) and passes that to a new Thread:

```
new Thread(new Game(gui, args)).start();
```

Running it gives me the following error

```
WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread 
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

Now, I am not sure how to pass the Virtual Machine Argument -XstartOnFirstThread in IntelliJ.

I tried copying the argument into debug configurations but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the argument in the box that would normally be labeled `VM options`.

In your screen shot you have `-cp bohnanza-demo`

So just add the argument after it. Final should be `-cp bohnanza-demo -XstartOnFirstThread`

Comment: The VM options box only came up after I checked "add VM options" after clicking on "Modify Options". Apparently, vmargs are different from program arguments. There's an option to add "Program Arguments", which are added to the main-method's "args"-Array, correct? And if so, then where are the VM Arguments  added to the program ?